# Referring to a child view from the parent view on click or tap event in TI

Tags: view, appcelerator, scrollable

In appcelerator TI code -  I have a month scrollable view to which I have added week views and to which I have added days as views.

The expectation on click event of a day I should be able to retrieve properties of the date. However on singletap event I am getting reference to the week view and not able to get the child view "days view. how can I get a reference to the days view on single tap to click event?

```
Code -Widget.js 


var args = arguments[0] || {};
var Moment = require('alloy/moment');

var ROWS = 6;
var COLUMNS = 7;

_.defaults(args, {

    // Data
    current_date: Moment(),
    active_dates: [],
    min_date: Moment().subtract(6, 'months'),
    max_date: Moment().add(6, 'months'),

    // Style
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    dateBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
    todayBackgroundColor: '#af80',
    dateTextColor: '#fff',
    todayTextColor: '#000',
    activePinColor: '#f39911',
    inactivePinColor: 'transparent',
    selectedBackgroundColor: '#60f39911',
    fontFamily: '',

    // Behaviour
    allowInactiveSelection: false,
    fillMonth: false,
    enablePastDays: false

});

var active_dates = args.active_dates ? getMomentDates(args.active_dates) : [];
var current_page = 0;

/////////////
// Methods //
/////////////

function refreshArrows() {
    $.leftBtn.opacity = current_page <= 0 ? 0.4 : 1;
    $.rightBtn.opacity = current_page >= $.monthScroll.views.length - 1 ? 0.4 : 1;
}

function getDayLabels() {
    var days = Moment.weekdaysMin();
    days.push(days.shift()); // Moment week has Sunday at index 0
    _.each(days, function(day, i) {
        var width = Math.floor($.calendar.rect.width / COLUMNS);
        var $label = $.UI.create('Label', {
            classes: ['dayLabel'],
            width: width,
            text: day.charAt(0),
            left: i * width,
            font: {
                fontFamily: args.fontFamily
            }
        });

        $.dayLabels.add($label);
    });
}

function getMomentDates(dates) {
    return _.map(dates, function(date) {
        return Moment(date);
    });
}

function isInMomentsList(date, dates) {
    return _.find(dates, function(day) {
        return date.isSame(day, 'day');
    });
}

function getDayContainer(number) {
    var $this = $.UI.create('View', {
        classes: ['day'],
        width: Math.floor($.monthScroll.rect.width / COLUMNS),
        height: Math.floor($.monthScroll.rect.height / ROWS),
        backgroundColor: args.dateBackgroundColor,
        opacity: 1,
        date: null,
        active: null,
    });
    $this.add($.UI.create('Label', {
        classes: ['dayNumber'],
        color: '#fff',
        text: number,
        font: {
            fontFamily: args.fontFamily
        }
    }));
    $this.add($.UI.create('View', {
        classes: ['dayDot'],
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    }));

    return $this;
}

function setItemDate($item, date) {
    $item.date = date;
    $item.children[0].text = date.date();
}

function setItemActive($item, active) {
    $item.active = active;
    $item.children[1].backgroundColor = active ? args.activePinColor : args.inactivePinColor;
}

function setItemToday($item, is_today) {
    $item.backgroundColor = is_today ? args.todayBackgroundColor : args.dateBackgroundColor;
    $item.children[0].color = is_today ? args.todayTextColor : args.dateTextColor;
}

function setItemCurrent($item, current) {
    $item.opacity = current ? 1 : 0.5;
}

function getMonthView(month, year) {
    var month_rows = [];
    var start_date = Moment().month(month).year(year).startOf('month').startOf('week');
    var end_date = Moment().month(month).year(year).endOf('month').endOf('week');

    // Month skeleton
    var $month_view = $.UI.create('View', {
        classes: ['month'],
        month: month,
        year: year,
        backgroundColor: args.backgroundColor,
        ready: false
    });

    // Month activity indicator
    var $loader = Ti.UI.createActivityIndicator({
        style: OS_IOS ? Ti.UI.iPhone.ActivityIndicatorStyle.BIG : Ti.UI.ActivityIndicatorStyle.BIG,
        center: {
            x: '50%',
            y: '50%'
        }
    });
    $month_view.add($loader);
    $month_view.__loader = $loader;
    $loader.show();

    return $month_view;
}

function buildMonth($month_view, dates) {
    if (!$month_view || $month_view.ready) return;
    var start_date = Moment().month($month_view.month).year($month_view.year).startOf('month').startOf('week');
    var end_date = Moment().month($month_view.month).year($month_view.year).endOf('month').endOf('week');
    var $days_container = Ti.UI.createView({
        height: Ti.UI.FILL,
        width: Ti.UI.FILL
    });

    // Separators
    for (var i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        $days_container.add($.UI.create('View', {
            classes: ['hr'],
            top: (i+1) * Math.floor($.monthScroll.rect.height / ROWS)
        }));
    }

    // Add day containers
    for (var d = 0; d < ROWS*COLUMNS; d++) {
        var curday = Moment(start_date).add(d, 'days');
        // If fillMonth is disabled, add only this month's days
        if (curday.month() === $month_view.month || args.fillMonth == true) {
            var $curview = getDayContainer(curday.date());
            var row = Math.floor(d/COLUMNS);
            var col = d % COLUMNS;

            setItemDate($curview, curday);
            setItemActive($curview, isInMomentsList(curday, dates));
            setItemCurrent($curview, !curday.isBefore(Moment(), 'day') || (args.enablePastDays == true && (curday.month() === $month_view.month)));
            setItemToday($curview, curday.isSame(Moment(), 'day'));

            $curview.top = row * ($curview.height);
            $curview.left = col * ($curview.width);

            $days_container.add($curview);
        }
    }

    $month_view.add($days_container);
    $month_view.ready = true;
    $month_view.__loader.hide();
}

function buildCalendar() {
    $.main.removeEventListener('postlayout', buildCalendar);

    // Add top labels
    getDayLabels();
    // Create the calendar views
    var curmonth_index = -1; var i = 0;
    for (var m = Moment(args.min_date); m.diff(Moment(args.max_date)) <= 0; m.add(1, 'months')) {
        if (m.isSame(Moment(), 'month')) curmonth_index = i;
        var monthview = getMonthView(m.month(), m.year());
        $.monthScroll.addView(monthview);
        i++;
    }

    $.monthScroll.currentPage = current_page = curmonth_index > 0 ? curmonth_index : 0;
    refreshCalendarMonth(current_page);
    refreshArrows();
}

function refreshCalendarMonth(m) {
    var month_date = Moment().month($.monthScroll.views[m].month).year($.monthScroll.views[m].year);

    $.monthName.text = month_date.format('MMMM').toUpperCase();
    $.monthYear.text = month_date.format('YYYY');

    buildMonth($.monthScroll.views[m], args.active_dates);

    if (current_page - 1 > -1) buildMonth($.monthScroll.views[m-1], args.active_dates);
    if (current_page + 1 < 12) buildMonth($.monthScroll.views[m+1], args.active_dates);
}

///////////////
// Listeners //
///////////////

$.main.addEventListener('postlayout', buildCalendar);

$.monthScroll.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    if (e.currentPage === current_page) return;
    current_page = e.currentPage;
    refreshArrows();
    refreshCalendarMonth(current_page);
});

$.monthScroll.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (!e.source.date || (!e.source.active && !args.allowInactiveSelection) || (args.enablePastDays == false && e.source.date.isBefore(Moment(), 'day'))) return;

    e.source.animate({ backgroundColor: args.selectedBackgroundColor, duration: 150, autoreverse: true });

    $.trigger('selected', {
        date: e.source.date,
        active: e.source.active
    });
});

$.leftBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    $.monthScroll.movePrevious();
});

$.rightBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    $.monthScroll.moveNext();
});

//////////
// Init //
//////////

$.monthName.font = {
    fontFamily: args.fontFamily,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
};
$.monthYear.font = {
    fontFamily: args.fontFamily,
    fontWeight: 'light'
};
```

Widget.xml

```
<Alloy>
     <Window backgroundColor="#110ee1" class="container" exitOnClose="true" id="widget" title="DailyRead" top="0">
    <View id="main">
        <View class="bar" id="header">
            <View class="hr" top="0"/>
            <View class="ctrlBtn" id="leftBtn">
                <ImageView id="leftArrow"/>
            </View>
            <View class="headerText">
                <Label id="monthName"/>
                <Label id="monthYear"/>
            </View>
            <View class="ctrlBtn" id="rightBtn">
                <ImageView id="rightArrow"/>
            </View>
            <View bottom="0" class="hr"/>
        </View>
        <View class="sp1/2"/>
        <View id="calendar">
            <View id="dayLabels"/>
            <View backgroundColor="#fff" class="hr" height="2"/>
            <ScrollableView id="monthScroll"/>
        </View>
    </View>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: So what exactly is the question? And where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the question I would add more information to the day view. E.g. if you create everything through a loop just add month, weeks to the day view as a property. Then set all views but the day view to `touchEnabled:false` and just add the click event to the day view. Then you can read `event.source.day/event.source.week/event.source.month` inside the click-event.

If that doesn't help please add some example code to your question.